# How to use a massive JavaScript String replace() to translate a page?

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm new with Javascript.

I would like to translate my page without another html page.

To do this, I'm experimenting this code:

```
<a href="javascript:myFunction()"><img src="img/Fr-Flag.png"></a>
<a  href="javascript:myFunction2()"><img src="img/UK-Flag.png"></a>
<h2 id="translate">Title</h2>
```

And a javascript:

```
<script>
            function myFunction() {
            var str = document.getElementById("translate").innerHTML; 
            var res = str.replace("Title", "Titre");
            document.getElementById("translate").innerHTML = res;
        }
            function myFunction2() {
            var str = document.getElementById("translate").innerHTML; 
            var res = str.replace("Titre", "Title");
            document.getElementById("translate").innerHTML = res;
        }
</script>
```

This method works, but I find this method very heavy, I must write the text 3 times...
So, can I put the translation in another file (js file?) ? How to do this ?

Comment: Templating... DustJS is an example of a clientside templating engine, which might make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks blex for your answer, I will take a look at this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, without using any special framework, library or even external file, I would store the translations in a Javascript object and call a single function to refresh it with the language as parameter.

```
<a href="javascript:doTranslate('fr')"><img src="img/Fr-Flag.png"></a>
<a  href="javascript:doTranslate('en')"><img src="img/UK-Flag.png"></a>
<h2 id="title">Title</h2>
<p id="content">Content</p>
```

And the Javascript becomes

```
<script>
        var translations= { 'en' : 
                                {'title' : 'Title', 'content' : 'Content of the document...'},
                            'fr' : 
                                {'title' : 'Titre', 'content' : 'Contenu du document'}
                          };
        function doTranslate(language) {
            for(id in translations[language]) {
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = translations[language][id];
            }
        }
</script>
```

This method is intended to be as close to your example as possible. I think it is simple and quite flexible: you just have to update `translations` when you add new elements to translate (as I did in this example). You certainly would have to ensure the language and the translations are present, that all the forbidden characters have properly been encoded...

Note that there are plenty of frameworks and libraries that can help to  manage it  on the client (browser) side or on the server side.

Comment: I like this method, I understand it !

Comment: Well I tried to be as close to your example as possible.

Comment: It's pretty the same, the script will be so big !

Comment: @Guillaume Your code involved a function requiring the same amount of lines  per element and per language. How can this solution be the same? Furthermore, if you don't want to use external files or tools, you will have to write your translations somewhere. There is no miracle.

Comment: This new code works, and with multiple contents! I think I will use it !! Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be using constants.

```
var languages = {
    EN: {title: 'Title'},
    FR: {title: 'Titre'},
};
var currentLanguage = 'EN';
var html = `
   <a href="javascript:myFunction()"><img src="img/Fr-Flag.png"></a>
   <a  href="javascript:myFunction2()"><img src="img/UK-Flag.png"></a>
   <h2 id="translate">${languages[currentLanguage].title}</h2>
`;
```